# Insert into Nhibernate Subclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We have two schemas one database, we can only change one schema.

The reason we are doing this is we have one-to-one mappings i.e. we need add extra fields to a Club table. So we have subclassed a table from the schema we cannot change.

We would like to Insert into the child table only, as the base table already has a record that exists, but we need to do our initial insert into our table called OurClub

We need the parent table TheirClub that has links to other data in the system, by using this we dont need to remap entities that have already bieng mapped beforehand.

```
public class OurClub : TheirClub
{
    public virtual int ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClubName { get; set; }

}

public class TheirClub //The schema we cant change
{
    public virtual int ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> Contacts { get; set; }

}
```

Whenever trying to Insert into OurClub it also trys to insert into TheirClub. We dont want this behaviour.

Are there any suggestions to the way around this?

Comment: Must you sub-class? Can you not have OurClub completely separate, use a common abstract base class or use an interface?

Comment: Yes must SubClass as theirs is the base...and is already mapped with the majority of the properties

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OurClub
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TheirClub OldClub { get; set; }
    // Additional Properties here

    // Use Properties like this to have the same References as TheirClub
    public virtual OtherEntity Other
    {
       get { return OldClub.Other; }
       set { OldClub.Other = value; }
    }
}

public class OurClubMap : ClassMap<OurClub>
{
    public OurClubMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("OldClub"); // inherits the id of the original
        // or
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLow("100");  // has its own id

        References(x => x.OldClub);
    }
}
```